# View PHP pages in Eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse

I have installed eclipse PDT for PHP development.
I want to test my "hello world" page but I can't get it to run.

I select my index.php created page and select "run as PHP Web Application" but all I get is an "unable to connect" error.

What is not clear to me is whether PDT contains a php server for testing purpose (in this case how do I configure it) or I do have to install apache/php on my development machine?

I'm on archlinux.

Comment: I can't answer your eclipse question (hence the comment) but you can probably get by with the [built in web server](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php)

Comment: You'll have to run your own server.

Comment: A page wont do it without a webserver. But you can use the console depending of the type of application your going to make.

Comment: Use a LAMP stack like XAMPP, WAMP or MAMP to run your PHP application. They work out of the zip. Just place your project root of eclipse inside the document root of the LAMP stack. Start at least Apache server in the control panel in one of those stacks and browse to `http://localhost/dirname_of_your_eclipse_project`

Comment: are you using apache or nginx for you localhost?

Comment: You need to have a server side compiler Apache, IIS, etc. Then you need to configure your eclipse running server configuration then you will be able to run your app through eclipse (but it's still using your apache or IIS)